# Retrive a value of a session stored in an associative array CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I am trying to retrieve the primary key that I stored in a session but I can't find a way to print it.

Here is **my controller** code

```
$usr_result = $this->Judge_Model->get_user($username, $password);

    if ($usr_result > 0)
    {
      //setting the session variables
      $sessiondata = array('login' => TRUE,'JudgeName' => $username,'uid' => $uresult[0]->JudgeID);
      $sessiondata = array($this->session->set_userdata($sessiondata));
      redirect("JudgingApp/MainMenu");
```

**My model**

```
 function get_user($usr, $pwd)
     {
          $sql = "select * from Judge where JudgeName = '" . $usr . "' and JudgePass = '" . $pwd . "' ''";
          $query = $this->db->query($sql);
          return $query->num_rows();
     }
```

and the page that I want to print it on

```
public function MainMenu()
    {
      $data['Poster'] = $this->Judge_Model->get_Posters();
      $this->load->view('JudgingApp/MainMenu',$data);
      if (isset($this->session->userdata['JudgeName']))
      {
          echo $this->session->userdata['JudgeName'];
          echo $this->session->userdata['uid'];
          echo $this->session->userdata['Pass'];
      }
      else
      {
        echo nothing;
      }
    }
```

I just want to print for debugging purposes and ensure that the value is being passed not so much that I want to show the user their ID.  I need the PK for another function so I need to make sure I can access it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**In Controller**

```
$usr_result = $this->Judge_Model->get_user($username, $password);

if (!empty($usr_result))
{
  $sessiondata = array(
            'login' => TRUE,
            'JudgeName' => $username,
            'uid' => $uresult[0]['JudgeID']
        );

    if (!$this->session->set_userdata($sessiondata)) {
        echo "Failed to set session";
    } else {
        redirect("JudgingApp/MainMenu");
    }    
}
else
{
    echo "No Data Found";
}

public function MainMenu()
{
    $data['Poster'] = $this->Judge_Model->get_Posters();

    if (isset($this->session->userdata['JudgeName']))
    {
        # To print this on view you need to add this in view. Not in controller. Or Bind it to $data and pass it
        echo $this->session->userdata['JudgeName'];
        echo $this->session->userdata['uid'];
        echo $this->session->userdata['Pass'];
    }
    else
    {
        echo nothing;
    }
    $this->load->view('JudgingApp/MainMenu',$data);
}
```

**In Model**

```
function get_user($username, $password)
{

    $array = array('JudgeName' => $username, 'JudgePass' => $password);
    $this->db->where($array);
    $query = $this->db->get('Judge');
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: So I tried the code above and made some changes however no matter what I do it always redirects me to the next page.  I tried to see what happens when I don't redirect and it says session failed to set Skipping Numeric Key 0.  I also get undefined variable for uresult and username and password

Comment: I realized that return numrows only returns the numbers that matched-_-  Its always returning 1 and nothing else.  It returns 0 if nothing matched